# Negative optimism resulting in better adjusted model performance

Tags: bootstrap, optimism

After carrying out 200 bootstraps to estimate the optimism around the net benefit of a model developed using stepwise BIC logistic regression, I'm getting a negative value meaning that when subtracted from the apparent net benefit I end up with an improvement. Has anyone else come across this before? I'm not looking for advice on variable selection methods, I realise there are alternatives to stepwise which are more robust.